# Not able to redirect to another page after clicking on submit button django

Tags: python, django

- So, I have implemented a bit of post, get and update in the following code. After submitting the values into the database. The return redirect is not changing the page to `UserProfile.html` which in `urls.py` is `user_profile`
- Code

`urls.py`

`path('user_profile', views.user_profile, name="user_profile"),`

`views.py`

```
def edit_profile(request):
    try:
        # checking if the user exist in UserProfile through the logged in email id
        user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
        # if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES:
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            name = UserProfile.objects.all()
            response_data = {}
            # user_img = request.FILES['user_img']
            name = request.user.username
            emailID = request.user.email
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            college_name = request.POST.get('college_name')
            branch = request.POST.get('branch')

            # response_data['user_img'] = user_img
            response_data['name'] = name
            response_data['emailID'] = emailID
            response_data['phone'] = phone
            response_data['college_name'] = college_name
            response_data['branch'] = branch
            # updating the current logged in user values
            user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
            if(user_data.emailID == request.user.email):
                UserProfile.objects.filter(emailID = request.user.email).update(
                    name = name,
                    emailID = emailID,
                    phone = phone,
                    college_name = college_name,
                    branch = branch
                )
            return redirect('/user_profile')
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        name = UserProfile.objects.all()
        response_data = {}
        # creating new user
        if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
            # user_img = request.FILES['user_img']
            name = request.user.username
            emailID = request.user.email
            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            college_name = request.POST.get('college_name')
            branch = request.POST.get('branch')

            # response_data['user_img'] = user_img
            response_data['name'] = name
            response_data['emailID'] = emailID
            response_data['phone'] = phone
            response_data['college_name'] = college_name
            response_data['branch'] = branch
            try:
                # checking if the user exist
                user_data = UserProfile.objects.get(emailID = request.user.email)
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                # if the user doesn't exist create the user
                UserProfile.objects.create(
                    name = name,
                    emailID = emailID,
                    phone = phone,
                    college_name = college_name,
                    branch = branch
                )
            return redirect('/user_profile')
    else:
        # if the profile is already created fetch the values
        context = {
            'name' : user_data.name,
            'emailID' : user_data.emailID,
            'phone' : user_data.phone,
            'college_name' : user_data.college_name,
            'branch' : user_data.branch
            }
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'context' : context})
    return redirect('/user_profile')
```

- I have also tried the `return HttpResponseRedirect`. But that is also not working for me.

Comment: Did you try `return redirect('user_profile')` or `return redirect('app_name:user_profile')` ?

Comment: I tried both now, they didn't worked

Comment: Reduce the size of your code first. You just abuse `try-except` with the way you use it (just putting all of your code inside it).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That is serving the logic for me, and how would that any how affect the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

change except

```
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
```

and remove "/" from redirect

```
return redirect('user_profile')
```